# Mapping of ViewModel with SelectList in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I'm struggling to find the correct approach on SO for what I am currently doing, so I thought I would ask.

Here is my simplified code:

The entities are nested types based on using them with EF CodeFirst and the ViewModel is being mapped with AutoMapper.

When posting the form the ModelState is not valid due to the dropdownlist being mapped to model.CourseId and displaying my Course data.. i.e. CourseId = 2, CourseList = Null, but also having the [Required] attribute, really only CourseId is required but I also needed a relevant error message.

I then thought that in my Create GET & POST actions the view should probably just have the CourseId but I still need to display it as a dropdown and populate it and I was unsure as how to do that correctly.

I may also not be understanding how this should be used correctly and if I even need CourseName, i.e. since the Course already exists in the database I just want a foreign key to it, which will still let me show the selected course.

I'm also planning to break out all this mapping and data setting in my controller actions into a separate service layer but at the moment its a small prototype.

```
// Entities
public class Recipe {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Course Course { get; set; }
}

public class Course {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// View Model
public class RecipeCreateViewModel {
    // Recipe properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Course properties, as primitives via AutoMapper
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    // For a drop down list of courses
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Course.")]
    public SelectList CourseList { get; set; }
}

// Part of my View
@model EatRateShare.WebUI.ViewModels.RecipeCreateViewModel
...
<div class="editor-label">
        Course
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @* The first param for DropDownListFor will make sure the relevant property is selected *@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseId, Model.CourseList, "Choose...")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId)
    </div>
    ...


    // Controller actions

    public ActionResult Create() {
        // map the Recipe to its View Model
        var recipeCreateViewModel = Mapper.Map<Recipe, RecipeCreateViewModel>(new Recipe());
        recipeCreateViewModel.CourseList = new SelectList(courseRepository.All, "Id", "Name");
        return View(recipeCreateViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RecipeCreateViewModel recipe) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var recipeEntity = Mapper.Map<RecipeCreateViewModel, Recipe>(recipe);
            recipeRepository.InsertOrUpdate(recipeEntity);
            recipeRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } else {
            recipe.CourseList = new SelectList(courseRepository.All, "Id", "Name");
            return View(recipe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If CourseId is the Required property, then put the `[Required]` attribute on that and not on the List... But since it's not nullable you may not even need that. Remove it from the List.

Comment: By simplifying things ive made it slightly confusing.. the CourseId has a [Required] attribute on the entity model, used to make it a required field in the sql compact database via EFCodeFirst. I may have made the mistake of thinking that it transfers that to my view model because previously I was using the entities directly. I've removed the Required attribute from my CourseList property, that was definately a mistake.

Comment: Since there are no answers yet I would update the source at this and also post the exact error messages.

Comment: There was no error message, the ModelState was just not valid like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my particular problem just by doing the below.

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Course.")]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    // public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public SelectList CourseList { get; set; }
```

The view will use the DropDownListFor helper to map the drop down to my CourseId and that's all I really needed.

On to another problem now with AutoMapper and why it is not mapping back to the Recipe entity in the POST Create action.

I probably first need to find a way to store the relevant Course name in the "CourseName" property.